# Android changing paint color runtime

Tags: android, colors, paint

I'm creating some square runtime and gives this codes for this :

```
        mBorderPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
        mBorderPaint.setShadowLayer(DisplayUtil.dip2px(getContext(), 2.0f), 0, 0, Color.parseColor("#33000000"));
```

And i want to change

```
mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
```

code to

```
mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
```

in application running. So when user touch somewhere in screen except creating square i'm getting toast message perfectly, but color not change. here is the changing part of my code ;

```
 if (mGone&& goneRect(x,y)&&!mInDelete&&!mInController&&!mContentRect.contains(x, y))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Your message.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));

            }
```

so i'm getting Toasted "Your message" perfectly however color changing not happened. How can i change this in application run ?

Comment: You need to call invalidate(). Paint was applied, but the view itself didn't redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `invalidate()` within your `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`. 
With this, your view can "refresh" your paint

Comment: this.invalidate(); is solve my problem. Thank you so much :)